How to Expose Python Enum as "Constants" without the Class Name All At Once
The following code creates three "constants" that can be used without the enum's class name before each one. Is there a way to do this to all members of the enum without having an explicit line of code for each member as shown here?
import enum

class Test(enum.Enum):
    ONE = 1
    TWO = 2
    THREE = 3

ONE = Test.ONE
TWO = Test.TWO
THREE = Test.THREE

Basically, is there an efficient way of doing this for an enum with 20-30 members all at once?

I wouldn't recommend to do that as the name of enum shows belonging. For example it's intuitive that january is working month from the following code:
class WorkingMonth(enum.Enum):
    JANUARY = "january"
    FEBRUARY = "february"
    ...

# WorkingMonth.JANUARY

There's no point in skimping on symbols in this case. Moreover, this increases the chance of potential error if you have enums with different names but intersecting values:
class ServerFormats(enum.Enum):
    MP3 = "mp3"
    WAV = "wav"


class ClientFormats(enum.Enum):
    MP3 = "mp3"
    FLAC = "flac"

# ServerFormats.MP3 and ClientFormats.MP3 will conflict

In a word, I would say that this is rather bad practice.

globals().update(Test.__members__)

Code linters will probably complain about undefined names, though, since they won't track that the member names came from an enum.
Also, as Victor mentions, be very careful about conflicting names from different enums.
